# Clear textbox without Jquery or hard coding an element

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs, textbox

I have a textbox that will dropdown a list of autocomplete options to fill in the textbox once the user enters the first three characters. Upon clicking on one of the autocomplete options, I want the textbox to clear itself. Here is what that element looks like right now:

```
 <label
      className="searchSecondary_userFilterFacet"
      hidden={!this.state.isExpanded}
    >
      <div
        className="data-uk-autocomplete"
        id="userFilterTypeahead"
        ref={elem => (this.userFilterTypeahead = elem)}
      >
        <input
          id="textInput_userSearch"
          onKeyUp={this._handleNewUser}
          placeholder="Search Users"
          type="text"
          ref={input => (this.userInput = input)}
        />
      </div>
      {userModifiers}
    </label>
```

I am using React. Here is what my code to clear the textbox currently looks like:

```
componentDidMount() {
let element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.userFilterTypeahead);

//bind selection event for user filter autocompletion uikit
$('#userFilterTypeahead').on(
  'selectitem.uk.autocomplete',
  function(event, data, acobject) {
    $('#textInput_userSearch').val('');
    this._editUsersBuffer(data.value, true, true);
  }.bind(this)
);
```

}

First and foremost I need to remove the Jquery line that is actually clearing the checkbox. I found that replacing it with `this.userInput.value=""` had no effect and neither did `event.target.value=""`. Secondly, I would like to remove the Jquery line `$('#userFilterTypeahead').on(
  'selectitem.uk.autocomplete',...` but I still need to be triggering my text clearing when the `selectitem.uk.autocomplete` event occurs. So, I would like to replace this Jquery and am baffled at the complexity that came with clearing a single text box.

Comment: `this.userInput.value = ''` should have worked. Can you console.log `this.userInput` and make sure that it exists and is not `undefined`? You may need to use a ref callback instead of doing an inline ref.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I logged `this.userInput` and got `<input type="text" id="textInput_userSearch" placeholder="Search Users" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: Are you sure that function is being called? Your code looks fine.

Comment: certainly am sure its being called since all I did was replace `$('#textInput_userSearch').val('');` with `this.userInput.value = ''` then the next line toss in a `console.log` and its printing

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using ref, but I would honestly bind it to state since I you can easily do this without using ref and it's commonly good practice to avoid using it unless you need to focus elements, not clear them. I've included an example for both.

If you rely a lot on auto complete I'd suggest using a module pre-built. But the example that I've linked below are very similar but it has been created to accept data. It'll just render a list of results that is shown below the input field when a query matches. https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest

**Example using state:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
  }
  clearInput = () => this.setState({ query: "" });
  setQuery = (evt) => this.setState({ query: evt.target.value });
  mockSelection = () => {
    if (this.state.query !== '') {
      return <div onClick={this.clearInput}>Click me to clear input</div>;
    }
    return null;
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text"
          placeholder="Please enter a query"
          value={this.state.query}
          onChange={this.setQuery}
        />
        {this.mockSelection()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Example using ref (Not recommended):**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
  }
  clearInput = () => this.inputQuery.value = "";
  setQuery = (evt) => this.setState({ query: evt.target.value });
  mockSelection = () => {
    if (this.state.query !== '') {
      return <div onClick={this.clearInput}>Click me to clear input</div>;
    }
    return null;
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text"
          ref={input => this.inputQuery = input}
          placeholder="Please enter a query"
          value={this.state.query}
          onChange={this.setQuery}
        />
        {this.mockSelection()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I fixed your snippets (they had errors), I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Sag1v Thanks! I didn't include them as working examples within the sandbox, thanks for fixing this as they have been copied from my codesandbox.io as quickly written examples :)

Comment: Im not entirely sure how your 'Click me to clear' div will look when rendered but it goes against what I am trying to accomplish. Upon the user selecting an autocompletion option, the textbox should clear. The user should not have to hit another button to clear the textbox after having already clicked on an autocomplete option.

Comment: @BobSmith You'll want to bind it to state and then the information that is shown with the mockSelection is a list of items that the query matches. The div is just an example of an item that should be selectable. Once you select this div (which is a metaphor element for item), it will clear the query field by clearing the state of the input. You should avoid using ref because it's not required and mixing React with jQuery it is not recommended as they are not meant to compliment each other. This is essentially how react-autosuggest works.